# How to create an executable jar without main but with main reference in manifest?

Tags: java, jar

I want to create an executable jar without main class because main class contains urls which need to be changed time to time.So,I want to keep it separately as .class file.

Comment: Why don't you just extract the urls and provide those via some file or other means of configuration?

Comment: I appreciate the comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bend the tool to model your use case.

Instead design your application to use property files for such configuration information.

Seriously: don't start inventing your own solutions when there are well-known and tested solutions coming off the shelf.

And even when you don't want to use property files, your problem could be solved differently. For example by moving these URLs into a separate class.

The real answer here is that you learn how to approach your problem with "default Java" techniques.